# What can I do after finish Fulton's book?

Tags: soft-question

I'm sorry if this question sounds a little vague.

I'm about to finish Fulton's algebraic curves book and I would like to know what's next. I'm looking for something deeper in algebraic curves. I'm a beginner in this subject and I'm felling a little lost.

Is there an "obvious" next step after study Riemann-Roch theorem? or it's depending of the branch you follow? if does, which branches can I follow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've got _Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces_ by Rick Miranda on my shelf. I don't have Fulton so I can't compare them.

Comment: @JohnHabert http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf

Comment: Thanks for link. In trying to save it, I discovered I had downloaded it yesterday from another thread on here so I was wrong about not having Fulton. Miranda takes more time with general Riemann surfaces over complex numbers before moving to Riemann-Roch and related theorems. Book ends with sheaves and cohomology.